# Align blocks with each other as closely as possible

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a situation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BL3M7/ :

HTML:

```
<div class="block" style="height: 50px">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
```

I want block 4 to be aligned as closely to block 1 as possible. Of course I could just use `margin-top` like http://jsfiddle.net/BL3M7/2/, but I can't do this, because block sizes' heights and width varies from page to page. So, is it possible to achieve such effect without `margin`?

Comment: If you add height:auto in .block class they will be as close possible but I am not sure its sit correct to ur requirement. http://jsfiddle.net/BL3M7/6/

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to try a CSS3 solution then you could use column-count to achieve something similar?

This technique will run top to bottom, rather than left to right, so be careful with the order of your HTML content.

I've added a container to your code:

```
<div class="block-container">
  <div class="block" style="height: 50px">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
</div>
```

Then some CSS

```
.block-container {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%; 
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BL3M7/4/)**

NOTE: Unfortunately this won't work in IE9 and below.  You may need a JS fallback if you want to support those.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can't be done with just css. But there are great Javascript solutions that do exactly what you want!

Have a look at: http://masonry.desandro.com/

or if you need some more options: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/